# lstrip(), rstrip() for lists

Tags: python, list

I have a bunch of huge lists with integers. These lists may start or end with a couple of zeroes.

Is there an easy way for strip either the zeroes on the left or right side from the list?
Something analogous to `lstrip()` or `rstrip()` for strings?

The data looks like

```
[0,0,0,1,2,3,4]
```

or

```
[1,2,3,4,0,0,0]
```

I must be able to individually `lstrip()` or `rstrip()`.  I do not need a strip from both sides of the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.dropwhile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
>>> L = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0]
>>> list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, L))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 0]
```

Comment: And for the rstrip() variant: `reversed(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, reversed(L)))`

Comment: the rstrip() variant is in fact `list(reversed(list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, reversed(L)))))`

Answer (score 1):

There is a more efficient solution than the built-in `itertools.dropwhile()`. You can use the almighty `collections.deque`, which would be the ideal data structure for this task, because its left or right `pop` is `O(1)`. Here is the left-strip case, and the right-strip is going to be just the mirror image of it:

```
from collections import deque

def noLeadingZero(l):
    d = deque(l)
    for e in l:
        if e == 0:
            d.popleft()
        else:
            break
    return list(d)

l = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0]
print(noLeadingZero(l))
# Result:
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 0]
```

Let's test its performance against the following code that utilizes the built-in `itertools.dropwhile()`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
print(list(dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, l)))
```

Here is the performance test:

```
import timeit

print timeit.timeit(
setup= """from itertools import dropwhile
l = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0]""",
stmt="""list(dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, l))""") #2.308

print timeit.timeit(
setup= """from collections import deque
l = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0]
def noLeadingZero(l):
    d = deque(l)
    for e in l:
        if e == 0:
            d.popleft()
        else:
            break
    return list(d)""",
stmt="""noLeadingZero(l)""") #1.684 -> Win!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['10000', '000001']
map(lambda x: x.strip('0'), l)

>>> ['1', '1']
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing your lists contains strings of the integers?
Like `['001','100']` as opposed to `[001,100]`?

Try `[x.strip('0') for x in bigList]`.  See `str.split` in [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: (by the way, there also exist (surprise,surprise) functions `lstrip` and `rstrip`...