# Clean a list from leading certain instances

Tags: python

I would like to clean a list from leading occurrences of `'a'`. That is, `['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']` should become `['b', 'b']` and at the same time `['b', 'a', 'a', 'b']` should be kept unchanged.

```
def remove_leading_items(l):
    if len(l) == 1 or l[0] != 'a':
        return l
    else:
        return remove_leading_items(l[1:])
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: is there only 2 unique values in list? and what should be output if input list is `['a','a','b','b','a','a']`?

Comment: This looks a bit like *Prolog*. @AkshayNevrekar: What part of "*Clean a list from __leading__ certain instances*" needs more clarification? Then, how is the fact that there are 2 (or more, or less) unique values relevant? "`['b', 'a', 'a', 'b']` *should be kept unchanged*" should answer your 2nd question.

Comment: There may be many values. The expected output is `['b','b','a','a']` for your example.

Comment: I added my answer, which is more efficient than the built in `dropwhile()` into the redirected question, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822513/6520041

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Immediately, you should be using a for loop. Recursion is generally not Pythonic. Second, use built in tools:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def remove_leading_items(l, item):
    return list(dropwhile (lambda x: x == item, l))
```

Or

```
return list(dropwhile(item.__eq__, l))
```

#### Edit

Out of curiosity, I did some experiments with different approaches to this problem:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
from functools import partial
from operator import eq

def _eq_drop(l, e):
    return dropwhile(e.__eq__, l)

def lam_drop(l, e):
    return dropwhile(lambda x:x==e, l)

def partial_drop(l, e):
    return dropwhile(partial(eq, e), l)
```

First, with a list that is entirely dropped: i.e. `(1, 1, 1, ...)`

```
In [64]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: list(_eq_drop(t0, 1))
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 389 µs per loop

In [65]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: list(lam_drop(t0, 1))
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop

In [66]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: list(partial_drop(t0, 1))
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 893 µs per loop
```

So `__eq__` is clearly the fastest in this situation. I like it, but it makes use of a dunder-method directly, which is sometimes frowned upon. The `dropwhile(partial(eq...` approach (wordy, yet explicit) is somewhere inbetween that and the sluggish, clumsy `lambda` approach comes last. Not surprising.

---

Now, when half is dropped, i.e `(1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0)`:

```
In [52]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: list(_eq_drop(t2, 1))
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 245 µs per loop

In [53]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: list(lam_drop(t2, 1))
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 652 µs per loop

In [54]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: list(partial_drop(t2, 1))
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 487 µs per loop
```

The difference isn't as pronounced.

---

As for why I say recursion isn't Pythonic, consider the following:

```
In [6]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: remove_leading_items(t0, 1)
   ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 405 ms per loop

In [7]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: remove_leading_items(t1, 1)
   ...:
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.7 µs per loop

In [8]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: remove_leading_items(t2, 1)
   ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 280 ms per loop
```

It performs catastrophically worse on all but the degenerate case of dropping 0 (well, 1 item).

### A fast, lest flexible approach

Now, if you know you always want a list, consider a highly iterative, very approach:

```
def for_loop(l, e):
    it = iter(l)
    for x in it:
        if x != e:
            break
    else:
        return []
    return [x, *it]
```

It performs better than using built-ins!

```
In [33]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: for_loop(t0, 1)
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 270 µs per loop

In [34]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: for_loop(t1, 1)
    ...:
10000 loops, best of 3: 50.7 µs per loop

In [35]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
    ...: for_loop(t2, 1)
    ...:
10000 loops, best of 3: 160 µs per loop
```

### Less fast, but more flexible!

Perhaps a good compromise that maintains flexibility is to use a generator-based approach:

```
In [5]: def gen_drop(l, e):
   ...:     it = iter(l)
   ...:     for x in it:
   ...:         if x != e:
   ...:             break
   ...:     yield x
   ...:     yield from it
   ...:

In [6]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: list(gen_drop(t0, 1))
   ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 287 µs per loop

In [7]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: list(gen_drop(t1, 1))
   ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 359 µs per loop

In [8]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: list(gen_drop(t2, 1))
   ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 324 µs per loop
```

#### Using a deque

Finally, the `deque` approach:

```
In [1]: from collections import deque
   ...:
   ...: def noLeadingZero(l, e):
   ...:     d = deque(l)
   ...:     for x in l:
   ...:         if e == x:
   ...:             d.popleft()
   ...:         else:
   ...:             break
   ...:     return list(d)
   ...:

In [2]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: noLeadingZero(t0, 1)
   ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 873 µs per loop

In [3]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: noLeadingZero(t1, 1)
   ...:
10000 loops, best of 3: 121 µs per loop

In [4]: %%timeit n = 10000; t0 = (1,)*n; t1 = (1,) + (0,)*(n-1); t2 = (1,)*(n//2) + (0,)*(n//2);
   ...: noLeadingZero(t2, 1)
   ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 502 µs per loop
```

Comment: I would prefer to only ever use the 2nd solution here, but i guess the first solution is needed for python2 `int`s

Comment: I know you were just using OP's template code, but let's not condone the use of `l` as a name (anti PEP8)

Comment: Why do you say recursion is not pythonic?

Comment: @Dror it is sluggish in Python, there's a lot of overhead to function calls in Python generally, and also, the overhead of more stack-frames always exists. Python isn't very accommodating of it, tail calls are not optimized, and by default, the maximum recursion depth is a low, only 1000.

Comment: @Dror also, if you are not careful, you will write inefficient algorithms by accident. Functional languages built with recursion in mind will have cons lists, with constant time `head`, and `tail` operations. In Python, the equivalent of tail, `mylist[1:]` is an O(N) operation. Your recursive algorithm is O(N^2) when it really should be O(N), even though using `mylist[1:]` is the most readable and natural inclination

Comment: @FatihAkici I've added comparisons to the `deque` based approach if you want to seem them in context.

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

```
def remove_leading(a_list, to_remove):
    i = 0
    while i < len(a_list) and  a_list[i] == to_remove:
        i += 1
    return a_list[i:]
```

#### Test Code:

```
print(remove_leading(list('aabb'), 'a'))
print(remove_leading(list('baab'), 'a'))
print(remove_leading([], 'a'))
```

#### Results:

```
['b', 'b']
['b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
[]
```

Comment: Won't work for empty list.

Comment: Also won't work for iterables, only sequences

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:-

```
s = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b','a','a','b']
def check(ls):
    new_ls = ls
    count = 0
    while ls[0]=='a':
        new_ls = ls[(count+1):]
        ls = new_ls
    return new_ls
print(check(s))
```

Comment: ...and how's this Pythonic?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Because it's written in Python

Comment: @jamylak lol. Nice to hear from you after a while.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
my_list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b']
item_i_hate = 'a'
for index in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[index] != item_i_hate:
        my_list = my_list[index:]
        break
```

Comment: Decent solution, and funny variable name, but just note the advantage of @juanpa.arrivillaga solution is that it works for any iterable, not just sequences